# com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision

Tags: seedstack

I have created simple `seedstack` web project through guideline mentioned on `http://seedstack.org/docs/basics/`

Undertow is also started with `seedstack:run`.

However, while accessing "hello" resource undertow throws below exception:

> ERROR 2018-07-25 21:37:34,468 XNIO-1 task-2   io.undertow.request
>   UT005023: Exception handling request to
>   /api/seed-w20/application/configuration
>
> null returned by binding at
>   org.seedstack.w20.internal.W20Module.configure(W20Module.java:51) (via
>   modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule ->
>   io.nuun.kernel.core.internal.injection.KernelGuiceModuleInternal ->
>   org.seedstack.w20.internal.W20Module)  but the 3rd parameter of
>   org.seedstack.w20.internal.FragmentManagerImpl.(FragmentManagerImpl.java:32)
>   is not @Nullable   at
>   org.seedstack.w20.internal.W20Module.configure(W20Module.java:51) (via
>   modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule ->
>   io.nuun.kernel.core.internal.injection.KernelGuiceModuleInternal ->
>   org.seedstack.w20.internal.W20Module)   while locating
>   org.seedstack.w20.internal.ConfiguredApplication
>       for the 3rd parameter of org.seedstack.w20.internal.FragmentManagerImpl.(FragmentManagerImpl.java:32)
>   while locating org.seedstack.w20.internal.FragmentManagerImpl   while
>   locating org.seedstack.w20.FragmentManager
>       for field at org.seedstack.w20.internal.rest.application.ApplicationConfigurationResource.fragmentManager(ApplicationConfigurationResource.java:38)
>   while locating
>   org.seedstack.w20.internal.rest.application.ApplicationConfigurationResource

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug introduced recently into the w20-bridge, which occurs when no `w20.app.json` configuration file is present.

You can workaround it by creating an empty-object `w20.app.json` file at the root of the classpath:

```
{}
```

You can also update the version of all w20-bridge dependencies to 3.2.4 which has a fix for it. This can be done by using the `dependencyManagement` section of your POM:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seedstack</groupId>
                <artifactId>seedstack-bom</artifactId>
                <version>18.4.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seedstack.addons.w20</groupId>
                <artifactId>w20-bridge-web</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seedstack.addons.w20</groupId>
                <artifactId>w20-bridge-web-bootstrap-3</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seedstack.addons.w20</groupId>
                <artifactId>w20-bridge-web-business-theme</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seedstack.addons.w20</groupId>
                <artifactId>w20-bridge-web-components</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seedstack.addons.w20</groupId>
                <artifactId>w20-bridge-rest</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seedstack.addons.w20</groupId>
                <artifactId>w20-bridge-specs</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
            </dependency>                                   
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

This fix will be included in the upcoming SeedStack 18.7.

Comment: Thanks Adrien !  I tried with dependency w20-3.2.4 version and it's works perfectly.